# How can one open link in new tab instead of model in angular, while passing parameters.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
modalInstance1 = $uibModal.open({
   animation: self.animationsEnabled,
   templateUrl: 'result_parametric.html',
   size: 'md',
   scope: $scope
});
```

How can we open a template in a new tab instead of uibModal.open? Where i can send scope: $scope?

Comment: you must build a template with router for it, then build a popup URL to open.

Comment: @Kai He can still not pass the entire `$scope` to the new tab. And doing modifications in the tab will not affect the tab from which it was opened.

Comment: @Arg0n we have a way to workaround it by passing needed `data` of `$scope` via `parameter` or `$localStorage`, in case of he REALLY want to implement this :D.